# Are there a best practices of generate a increment sequence number in sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I write a query to auto increase the sequence number of new record, Its works fine in single call.

```
insert into testTable (sequence_no) 
    case when exists (select sequence_no from testTable)
         then (select top(1) sequence_no +1 from testTable order by sequence_no desc)
         else '1'
    end as sequence_no
```

Then I add a thread remark on it, loop 100000 times, open 2 thread and run it same time.
thread 1:

```
declare @cnt INT =0;
while @cnt<100000
begin 
insert into testTable (sequence_no, thread_no) 
    case when exists (select sequence_no from testTable)
         then (select top(1) sequence_no +1 from testTable order by sequence_no desc)
         else '1'
    end as sequence_no, '1' as thread_no
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

thread 2:

```
declare @cnt INT =0;
while @cnt<100000
begin 
insert into testTable (sequence_no, thread_no) 
    case when exists (select sequence_no from testTable)
         then (select top(1) sequence_no +1 from testTable order by sequence_no desc)
         else '1'
    end as sequence_no, '2' as thread_no
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

The result around 70% request success, the others fail with

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'sequence_no'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.testTable'.

I thought it will be solve if I use a transaction on each request, but the result is samiliar, around 70% success ,and  others fail with PK duplicate.

Is it means my practise is bad for sequnce number generation?
Can someone give me a improvement?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you really using?

Comment: If you're using MySQL, then you "should" use [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: As for the problem, you have race conditions here. Why are you not using an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Larnu I test it on sql server, but I think the algotherm should be universal.

Comment: @CarlTin transferable SQL is a dream; every RDBMS uses different dialects, so you should be writing SQL for the RDBMS you are using. If yo are using SQL Server, then don't tag [[tag:mysql]], it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Best way: Let the DBMS care about it and use the built in autoincrement feature. Every major DBMS supports this ...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I simplified my situation, actually my sequence_no should have a prefix prcessing.

Comment: Also, be clear on what your actual requirements are. Most database autoincrement facilities do not guarantee an absence of gaps in the numbers. If you require *that*, it's an expensive operation to compute.

Comment: The prefix should be stored in a separate column, @CarlTin . If you then need a column with the prefix and the sequence value, then you use a computed column that concatenates the 2 as needed.

Comment: @Larnu What if I want the sequence no generate independently on each different prefix? Its like A001, A002..., B001, B002, etc.

Comment: It fails because you have created a race condition.

Comment: Using a prefix with a number like is a horrific anti-pattern. It indicates that you are putting value in your key which violates 1NF. But if you really need such a thing then you would probably want to look into sequences and create a sequence for each "prefix". Ugh!!

Comment: One method would be to use multiple `SEQUENCE`s, @CarlTin , which isn't ideal (depends how many prefixes you have). I smell an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) developing here.

Comment: if you don't want to use a sequence then you need to lock the table before the insert statement -- the problem is the table is not locked when the sub-queries run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each RDBMS system usually has it own "auto-number" (usually used for PrimaryKeys) setup.

MySql, Ms-Sql-Server, ORACLE (the article shows the 3 different syntaxes for each...just at one url)

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

PostGres:

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql/

Your question is tagged with (microsoft)sql-server, so I'll paste
that.

> Syntax for SQL Server The following SQL statement defines the
> "PersonKey" column to be an auto-increment primary key field in the
> "Person" table:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (
>     PersonKey int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>     LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     FirstName varchar(255)
> );
> ```

Do not reinvent the wheel.

So unless you are (trying) to INSERT a million rows in < 2 seconds....use what is already there for you.

Opinions.

You should not care that each primary-key is perfectly in sequence.  Aka, "gaps" should be Ok.

if you think you need perfect sequencing, you need to ask yourself "why".

a primary key needs to be unique.  having "order" helps with indexing.

but

1,2,3,6,7,9,11 are ordered.  (4,5,8 are missing, but does it really matter that they are missing?)

I will add that Ms Sql Server has added "sequences" since version 2016 (or was it 2014?)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2016

There are reasons to pick one over the other.

https://www.sqlshack.com/difference-between-identity-sequence-in-sql-server/

The 2 cent explanation is sequence can provide a range of values.  And it is not tied to a single table (like identity is).

But practically, you end up having more "gaps" in the values..because once a sequence is requested, the same value is never regenerated...even if the ~potential rows for INSERT do not actually make it as inserted-rows.

Comment: I will accept it , it's great to lead by some expert's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The first example in the question (`sequence_no +1`) is how **NOT** to do it! Instead, SQL Server has two ways you can do this, and either is acceptable:

1. Define the column as an [**identity**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16) column, and omit it from the `INSERT` completely:

   ```
   insert into testTable (thread_no) VALUES ('1')
   ```
2. Create a [**Sequence**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), and use the value from the sequence:

   ```
    insert into testTAble(sequence_no, thread_no) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR testTableSequence, '1')
   ```

Again, under no circumstances should you ever try to use `TOP 1 sequence_no+1` or `MAX(sequence_no)+1`. That is **wrong** in SQL Server (really, it's wrong in MySql, too).

Comment: Can you show me how to create multi sequence in one table?  
My final target is generate sequence no independently on each different prefix.
I'm so sorry that I'm pretty new on this.

Comment: No database supports a separate sequence per prefix. None. Instead, you have **one** sequence, where each prefix will have gaps and different starts. If you really need it, when querying the table you can use 'row_number()` to simulate consecutive 1,2,3 style ordering... just don't store the data that way.

Answer (score 0):

Du to concurrent access, if you want your code succed without any exception, must must LOCK the all table with an exclusive lock the time the transaction execute. So you must rewrite your code with :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
insert into testTable WITH (XLOCK, TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) (sequence_no) 
    SELECT case when exists (select sequence_no from testTable)
         then (select top(1) sequence_no +1 from testTable order by sequence_no desc)
         else '1'
    end as sequence_no;
COMMIT
```

But, this will be catastrophic for concurrent accesses... Locking all the table will take time, induce contention, generate deadlock !

It is why RDBMS offers internal increment as IDENTITY or SEQUENCES that are parts of the SQL ISO standard